# compareTo for string in alphanumeric order problem

Tags: java, compareto

```js
    //getFirstName method
    public String getFirstName()
    {
        String firstName = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf(' '));
        return firstName;
    }

    //getLastName method
    public String getLastName()
    {
        String lastName = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
        return lastName;
    }

    //alphaName method :: returns a String of the users's full name
    //in alphanumeric order;  returns a String with first and last named switched,
    //only if necessary; instance variable name is left unchanged
    // use the String class compareTo() method
    public String alphaName()
    {
        String compare = firstName.compareTo(lastName);
        if(compare < 0){
            return getFirstName() + getLastName();
        }
        else if(compare > 0){
            return getLastName() + getFirstName();
        }
        else{
            return getLastName() + getFirstName();
        }
        return compare;
    }
```

Hi there, I cannot figure out how to make my code in alphanumeric order. I have this now, and it is not outputting correctly. I didn't add the entire program, but this should be enough. I used the compare to, grabbed the methods getFirstName and getLastName, and it is not outputting correctly. Please help, thank you!

Comment: *it is not outputting correctly* so what is the problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a longer example array (your example is too short) and the result you want to have after being sorted.

Comment: What's the point of the `else if` if it's the same as the `else`?

Comment: @shmosel the else if is for greater than 0, the else is for if compare equals 0

Comment: @amin29 But they're doing the same thing.

Comment: @shmosel Oh sorry my bad I just realized that the code inside was the exact same, your correct that the else if is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

compareTo should return an int, not a String- you're attempting to store it into a String and not an int.  Change that to be "int compare" and it should work.

Comment: This is the right answer @JohnathanMinucco can you mark it as such if it helped you?

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
public String alphaName(String firstName, String lastName)
{
    int compare = firstName.compareTo(lastName);
    if(compare < 0){
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
    else if(compare > 0){
        return lastName + " " + firstName;
    }
    else{
        return lastName + " " + firstName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give reason for downvote. This solution works on java 8